# Codeigniter redirection on hosting server

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect

I have developed one project using codeigniter my problem is i am getting redirection problem on hosting server on my local system working fine

**Local system configuration details**

wamp server Apache/2.2.17 php 5.3.5

**hosting server configuration details**
PHP 5.2.17

if any other details kindly give me message.. please help me

Comment: Please use a little bit more punctuation :), and provide some details about your work. Codes, logs etc.

Comment: I have developed project called www.telugucinemalo.in using codeigniter framework in my localhost it working fine no redirection problem. But when i uploaded to domain hosting server i am getting 404 Page Not Found

Comment: @chilukuribhaskar PLease don't just repeat your question as a comment. Expand your question with configuration details, any log entries etc.  We can't be expected to know full and precise details of your setup without you telling us.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible problems:

1. Your index.php file isn't in your www folder on the server. Put it in the right place.
2. You changed your controller file's name so the default controller can't be found. Go to application/config/routes.php and change the default to whatever your default controller is.
3. Your application and system folders are not in www folder with index.php. Go into index.php and near the top you see it will define 2 variables for the locations of those folders. Direct it to where they are.

Comment: home controller is loading but sub controllers are not loading inner pages pages problem i am sending url which is not working please check it. http://www.telugucinemalo.in/Intheaters/currentRunning

Comment: Don't use the capital I for Intheaters:
http://www.telugucinemalo.in/intheaters/currentRunning

Answer (score 0):

This URL does not give a 404: http://www.telugucinemalo.in/intheaters/currentrunning

Seems your hosting server is **case sensitive** and your local server is not.